# Tensorflow Placeholder is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to understand how tensorflow works by coding a multilayer perceptron classifier. I'm using the MNIST dataset in this case. I want to create a neural network class that has its own tensorflow graph, and with it a function to train it. I know there are easier ways to do this but i'm trying to learn, I want to understand this error.

This is my code:

```
class neural_network_tensor:
def __init__(self, hidden_layers, learning_rate, input_size, output_size):
    self.graph=tf.Graph()
    with self.graph.as_default():
        layer_dim=[input_size]+hidden_layers+[output_size]
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_size])
        y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_size])
        #layers
        logits=[x]
        weights=[]
        biases=[]
        #hidden layers
        for i in range(len(layer_dim)-1):
            weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.zeros([layer_dim[i], layer_dim[i+1]])))
            biases.append(tf.Variable(tf.zeros([layer_dim[i+1]])))
            logits.append(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(logits[i],weights[i])+ biases[i]))
        self.y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits[-1])
        cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits[-1],
                                                                labels=y_true)
        self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
        self.optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(self.cost)
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(self.y_pred, y_true)
        self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print(x)

def train(self, num_iterations, batch_size, data, session):
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        # Get a batch of training examples.
        # x_batch now holds a batch of images and
        # y_true_batch are the true labels for those images.
        x_batch, y_true_batch = data.train.next_batch(batch_size)

        # Put the batch into a dict with the proper names
        # for placeholder variables in the TensorFlow graph.
        # Note that the placeholder for y_true_cls is not set
        # because it is not used during training.
        feed_dict_train = {x: x_batch,
                           y_true: y_true_batch}

        # Run the optimizer using this batch of training data.
        # TensorFlow assigns the variables in feed_dict_train
        # to the placeholder variables and then runs the optimizer.
        session.run(self.optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)

def print_accuracy(self, data, session):
    feed_dict_test = {x: data.test.images,
                  y_true: data.test.labels,
                  y_true_cls: data.test.cls}
    # Use TensorFlow to compute the accuracy.
    acc = session.run(self.accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict_test)

    # Print the accuracy.
    print("Accuracy on test-set: {0:.1%}".format(acc))


net=neural_network_tensor([1], 0.1, img_size_flat, 10)
with net.graph.as_default():
    sessi=tf.Session()
    net.train(5, 100, data, sessi)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 784), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

The "Placeholder:0" tensor is the x of the net. I would appreciate any help about how to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a plain old Python scope problem here. You define `x` in the `__init__` method but nowhere is the value `x` passed to anyone.

When you get to

```
    feed_dict_train = {x: x_batch,
                       y_true: y_true_batch}
```

in the `train` method, `x` is not defined, or is maybe a global. You either have to pass `x` back to the caller and hand it over to other methods, or you can assign it to the instance like `self.x = x` and use it that way, or the third way is to give it a name and fish it out from the graph by name before assembling the feed dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, I think that was it, but I am not entirely sure because now it gives me another error "Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_3". Should I initialize the variables in net.graph? how is it done?

Comment: I am not sure about this solution. The feed dictionary needs strings as keys. So it should likely be something like `{ 'x': x_batch...`. The problem is more how TF handles the scope of graphs. Note that the code you shared is not valid Python (as Peter mentions, syntax error on the `x`).

Comment: @ChristianDesivo: Initialization: this is a different problem, but you have to run [`sessi.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer) after the creation of session, before training to initialize the variables.

Comment: @EricPlaton: [`tf.Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) needs the tf.Tensor objects as keys to the feed dictionary.

Comment: @PeterSzoldan what if I only want to initialize the variables in the graph and not all the global variables? I guess my question is, and I haven't found anything about this in the documentation, is there other ways to initialize variables than with the global variables initializer?

Comment: @CristianDesivo: yes, you can initialize the variables one by one with [`tf.variables_initializer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variables_initializer). You pass a `var_list` argument with a list of the variables you want to initialize. [`tf.global_variables_initializer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer) is basically equivalent to `tf.variables_initializer( tf.get_collection( tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES) )` - it gets all the variables in the graph and initializes them.

Comment: @CristianDesivo: hey, happy to hear I was helpful! :) Upvote the comment please if you found it useful. ;) (Only saying because I see you're new here.)

Comment: @PeterSzoldan Thanks for the feedback. Just for the record, passing Tensor objects to the feed works if the objects are in scope. If not, one can use strings (the actual tensor name, typically used when loading a serialized graph).